# A non-trivial Hausdorff topology on X

Tags: general-topology

Let X be an infinite set. Is there a non-trivial Hausdorff topology on X such that contains an open finite set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, every topology contains the empty set as a finite open set. I assume you want a non-empty finite set. I assume that by non-trivial you mean not the discrete topology.

So, yes, there is such a topology. Write $X=Y\cup Z$ as the disjoint union of two sets. Endow $Y$ and $Z$ with any Hausdorff topologies you like, and $X$ with the coproduct topology. Now just choose $Y$ and $Z$ correctly to get what you need (notice that $Y$ and $Z$ are open in $X$). In particular, you can choose $Y$ to be finite (discrete) and $Z$ to be Hausdorff and non-discrete.